# How do I sucessfully import a csv file to Magento using Magmi?

Tags: magmi

My supplier has provided me with a CSV file which contains all the products they supply. I am trying to import this in to a empty Magento Store (No existing Products or Categories).

When I try to import the file I get 39000 errors! All stating 'attribute_set defined 'however there is a column for Attribute Set.

Any help would be greatfully accepted as this is driving me mad lol

Thanks
Tony

Comment: I've provided an answer, assuming your column name is incorrect.  You should post a snippet of the first few lines of your CSV so we can more accurately see what is wrong with your datasource file.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that attribute set column header is `attribute_set`.

If it's `Attribute Set` in your CSV, you can use the `Column Mapper` plugin to map it to the correct header name.

1. Go to your Magmi UI
2. Go to the **Configure Current Profile** section
3. Check the box next to the **Column mapper** plugin, then click the **Configure** link
4. In the **Mapped columns list** field, enter `Attribute Set` (the column header value you currently have in your CSV).  Now click anywhere on the page for the mapping area to appear.
5. A field **New name for col Attribute Set** will appear.  Enter `attribute_set` as the value.
6. Save your Magmi profile.

This will map the column `Attribute Set` to the correct column `attribute_set`